# Webstorm file dependencies in project pane

Tags: webstorm

How do you configure file dependencies in project pane? 
for example `.js` files automatically get added as a dependency of `.coffeescript` they're compiled from.

But source map files don't. How can I change that?

[image]

upd: here are the file watcher options:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure output paths in your file watcher accordingly to let WebStorm know where to look for your generated .map files. Please, can you provide a screenshot of your file watcher settings?

Comment: Oh. That's not what I am talking about. They are physically in the same folder, but webstorm knows that home-index.js derived from home-index.coffee and provides 'folding'. That way you don't have to see all the files in the project tree. What I would like to do is to set webstorm so it would know that home-index.map derived from .coffee file as well

Comment: your js and map files are produced by file watcher, aren't they? This is a watchers feature: produced files are grouped so that they have their original file as a parent in the Project View. But this only works if the output paths option is correctly configured

Comment: Alright, then it seems strange. Because both files(.js and .map) are generated by the same file watcher (check out my updated question)

Comment: not strange at all - .map files are not defined in output paths option. Just change it to '$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.map'